# Simplifying code: merging two functions into one - passing struct as a parameter?

Tags: c++, function, struct, singly-linked-list

I have the following (singly-linked list) two different structs:

```
struct Main {
    int data1;
    std::string some_data;
    Main *next;
}
struct Side {
    int data2;
    int data3;
    Side *next;
}
```

And the following two functions to remove only the first node from specific linked list `Main` or `Side`:

```
void DeleteFirstMain(Main *&pHeadMain)
{
    Main *MainToBeDeleted;

    if (pHeadMain == nullptr)
        std::cout << "List is already empty.";
    else
    {
        MainToBeDeleted = pHeadMain;
        pHeadMain = pHeadMain->next;

        /* Clears the memory occupied by first node*/
        delete MainToBeDeleted;
    }
}

void DeleteFirstSide(Side *&pHeadSide)
{
    Side *SideToBeDeleted;

    if (pHeadSide == nullptr)
        std::cout << "List is already empty.";
    else
    {
        SideToBeDeleted = pHeadSide;
        pHeadSide = pHeadSide->next;

        /* Clears the memory occupied by first node*/
        delete SideToBeDeleted;
    }
}
```

And everything works great.

However, I believe that the two functions could be merged into one and thus tidy up the code a little bit -- both functions do essentially the same thing, but with a different struct. This is pretty basic stuff, but in C++ I have no idea how to properly pass a "template" struct into a function as an argument.

As always, help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: use `std::list` ?

Comment: `template <class T> void DeleteFirst(T*& pHead)`? Though honestly this entire code looks very C-ish

Comment: If you really want singly linked list (e. g. for efficiency), then there's `std::forward_list` as well. Generally, there's little use in re-inventing the wheel - unless it is requested explicitly in a task for exercise (to gain better understanding).

Comment: I am not allowed to use any STL containers (teacher's guidelines). This code is just a part of my project, that is already working, I am just trying to optimalize it.

Comment: Then a template function is the way to go. Actually, I'd already make the node classes templates.

Comment: @UnholySheep Wow, this works amazingly fine. I cannot accept your post because your reply is a comment.

Comment: *'looks very C-ish'* - the point about this is that you have poor encapsulation. *Anybody* (or *any code*) could modify the list from anywhere, possibly doing harm to it. The very least thing you could do is making the `next` pointer private and give only those functions that shall modify the list access to by making them friends.